# Excel add-in doesn't work anymore in debug mode from Visual Studio

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I was working on my new office add-in for excel. Everything was great until it starts to say:

```
This add-in is no longer available: add-ins inserted during development are
only available during debugging from Visual Studio.
```

I AM debugging it by Visual Studio, but it still shows this message and doesn't load my add-in so I can debug it.

Any idea how to tell Excel that I'm still from visual studio, don't ban me!?

Comment: Try closing all Office applications and then clear the Office cache: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest#clear-the-office-cache

Comment: @RickKirkham I cleared the cache and restarted my computer, but unfortunately, it didn't work :(

Comment: You may have a try on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins#:~:text=In%20Excel%2C%20Word%2C%20or%20PowerPoint,to%20insert%20the%20add-in.) to see if it could help at least load the add-in successfully.